# Drag JSTree Node into an external div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jstree

I am using Jquery jsTree where i load my data into jstree with json. Below is my code to populate my jsTree

```
  $.ajax({
           async: true,
           type: "POST",
           url: "MasterPageDataService.asmx/GetAllSites",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (jsonData) {
           $("#divSitesTree").jstree({
                'core': {
                'data': jsonData
                 },
                "plugins": ['dnd', "themes", "json_data", "ui"]
               });},
           });
```

I get the data populated perfectly.

Now i want to drag a node and drop it onto div element. I have made my div drop able to serve the purpose like this

```
  $(".droppable").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                alert('dropped');
                // here i want the id of dropped node
            }
        });
```

I don't want to move the node from tree to anywhere , i just want to get the id of the node being dragged and dropped into div. But my problem is that m not even getting the drop event getting fired. e.g i don't get any alert at all.

I have googled the different solutions and tried this so far.

```
<script>
   $(function () {
   $('.drag')
   .on('mousedown', function (e) {
   return $.vakata.dnd.start(e, { 'jstree': true, 'obj': $(this),    'nodes': [{ id: true, text: $(this).text() }] }, '<div id="jstree-dnd" class="jstree-default"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-er"></i>' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
            });
        $(document)
            .on('dnd_move.vakata', function (e, data) {
                var t = $(data.event.target);
                if (!t.closest('.jstree').length) {
                    if (t.closest('.drop').length) {
                        data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-er').addClass('jstree-ok');
                    }
                    else {
                        data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-ok').addClass('jstree-er');
                    }
                }
            })
            .on('dnd_stop.vakata', function (e, data) {
                var t = $(data.event.target);
                if (!t.closest('.jstree').length) {
                    if (t.closest('.drop').length) {
                    $(data.element).clone().appendTo(t.closest('.drop'));
                    }
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

But what it does, it simply appends the node(icon+text) in my div. But that is not what i want. I just want to get the Id of the node inside an event where i can perform further operation based over the id of the node.

How do I accomplish this task with jsTree? Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I have found the solution. Below is the script to get the id of the    node being dragged and the id of the target where the node is being dropped

```
 $(document)
   .on('dnd_stop.vakata', function (e, data) {
    var t = $(data.event.target);
      if (!t.closest('.jstree').length) {
        if (t.closest('.drop').length) {
           alert(data.data.origin.get_node(data.element).id);//node id
           alert(data.event.target.id) //target id 
      }}});});
```

Comment: It works! Please note that the drop zone should have a `.drop` class for this script to work.